# How can I get FileWatcher to tell me the file modified is a folder?

Tags: java, file-io

In Java, I am using the procedure presented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html). Everything is working fine when I am interacting with files, but I am running into problems when dealing with folders.
The code does indeed detect that a new folder has been added/modified etc. but it does not tell me that is a folder and not a file.

It will say "foo has been added", this means foo can be a file or folder, and when I am trying to build a link out of that information, it matters.

What is the solution that I should adopt in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether it is a file or folder by using isFile() or isDirectory()

```
String filePath = watchEvent.context().toString();
File file = new File(filePath);
//here you can identify whether it is file or folder isFile() or isDirectory()
if(file.isFile()){
  //is a file 
}
if(file.isDirectory()){
 //is a directory
}
```

Hope the above may help you .